# regex for this cookie value?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a cookie with a long value, I have pasted an example below. I need to split on name value pairs and return, in this case "id" which from below corresponds to `167814329`.

I'm having trouble reading what syntax the developers have used here (I'm a analyst not dev engineer). In the past I have seen name value pairs used with = or '|' syntax as a separator.

It looks like the name value pair is like so:

```
%22id%22%3A167814329%2C

var usd = document.cookie.match(/(^| )user_session_data\=([^;]*)(;|$)/)[0]
var arr = usd.split('%22')
var ind = arr.indexOf('id');
var pair = arr[ind];
```

But pair is equal to "id" only, I was hoping to get this array value `%22id%22%3A167814329%2C` which I could then split.

What would be a clean regex to get 167814329?

Here is the example cookie value to search through:

```
user_session_data=%7B%22lastUpdated%22%3A1476155189.373%2C%22active%22%3Afalse%2C%22uType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22entitled%22%3Afalse%2C%22gift%22%3Afalse%2C%22stacked%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22usedsomestringFreeTrial%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22cancelled%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22email%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22userName%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22firstName%22%3Anull%2C%22salesChannel%22%3A%22cat%22%2C%22marketingOptIn%22%3Atrue%2C%22newIssueEmailNotifyEnabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22restartSubscriptions%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22id%22%3A167814329%2C%22purchaseType%22%3A%22NONE%22%2C%22futurePurchaseType%22%3A%22NONE%22%2C%22somestringStatus%22%3Anull%2C%22hasFuturePrivilege%22%3Afalse%2C%22rogersUser%22%3Afalse%2C%22suspendedStatus%22%3Anull%2C%22socialEmail%22%3A%22%22%2C%22somestringOffersStale%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesPrice%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesFreeTrial%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesOfferPackageId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsPrice%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsFreeTrial%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsOfferPackageId%22%3Anull%2C%22launchedFromReader%22%3Anull%2C%22userPaymentMethod%22%3Anull%2C%22iseligibleforfreetrial%22%3Atrue%2C%22loginTimeStamp%22%3A%22Tue%20Oct%2011%202016%2011%3A06%3A29%20GMT%2B0800%20(PHT)%22%2C%22latestSubscriptionSource%22%3Anull%7D;"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hanlet Escaño definitely has the most accurate answer, but if you *really* wanted to use regex you can. It was unclear whether you wanted `id%22%3a[ID]%2C` or just the ID, so here's both:

Full string: `(?:^| )user_session_data\=[^;]*(id%22%3A\d+%2C)[^;]*(?:;|$)`

Just the ID: `(?:^| )user_session_data\=[^;]*id%22%3A(\d+)%2C[^;]*(?:;|$)`

In the future, if you're having trouble with a regex, [this site](https://regex101.com/r/ThorYS/1) can be extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks Bern that regex does the trick. But now I'm not sure if I should live with what I have using json parse or change to regex! Thanks for the answer

Comment: Good answer Bern. These expressions can sometimes save lives!

Comment: Parsing the JSON will definitely make it easier to change in the future and it gives you access to all the fields if you need them later. It's also harder to break since it looks at all the data. If someone's email were, for example `id%22%3A123%2C@gmail.com` this expression would get super confused. That being said, maybe that isn't a concern for you and this quick and easy solution is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like if you remove the `user_session_data` at the beginning and the `;` at the end, you just got yourself a escaped string. You can [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) it, and get your id like this (it is actually a JSON object):

```
var obj = "%7B%22lastUpdated%22%3A1476155189.373%2C%22active%22%3Afalse%2C%22uType%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22entitled%22%3Afalse%2C%22gift%22%3Afalse%2C%22stacked%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22usedsomestringFreeTrial%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22cancelled%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22email%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22userName%22%3A%2220161010_gpc%40example.com%22%2C%22firstName%22%3Anull%2C%22salesChannel%22%3A%22cat%22%2C%22marketingOptIn%22%3Atrue%2C%22newIssueEmailNotifyEnabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22restartSubscriptions%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22id%22%3A167814329%2C%22purchaseType%22%3A%22NONE%22%2C%22futurePurchaseType%22%3A%22NONE%22%2C%22somestringStatus%22%3Anull%2C%22hasFuturePrivilege%22%3Afalse%2C%22rogersUser%22%3Afalse%2C%22suspendedStatus%22%3Anull%2C%22socialEmail%22%3A%22%22%2C%22somestringOffersStale%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesPrice%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesFreeTrial%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcabbagesOfferPackageId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsPrice%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsId%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsFreeTrial%22%3Anull%2C%22somestringcarrotsOfferPackageId%22%3Anull%2C%22launchedFromReader%22%3Anull%2C%22userPaymentMethod%22%3Anull%2C%22iseligibleforfreetrial%22%3Atrue%2C%22loginTimeStamp%22%3A%22Tue%20Oct%2011%202016%2011%3A06%3A29%20GMT%2B0800%20(PHT)%22%2C%22latestSubscriptionSource%22%3Anull%7D"

var myObject = JSON.parse(unescape(obj));
console.log(myObject.id); //167814329
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/orrt86cp/

Your JSON looks like this:

```
{  
   "lastUpdated":1476155189.373,
   "active":false,
   "uType":"none",
   "entitled":false,
   "gift":false,
   "stacked":"none",
   "usedsomestringFreeTrial":"none",
   "cancelled":"none",
   "displayName":"20161010_gpc@example.com",
   "email":"20161010_gpc@example.com",
   "userName":"20161010_gpc@example.com",
   "firstName":null,
   "salesChannel":"cat",
   "marketingOptIn":true,
   "newIssueEmailNotifyEnabled":false,
   "restartSubscriptions":[  

   ],
   "id":167814329,
   "purchaseType":"NONE",
   "futurePurchaseType":"NONE",
   "somestringStatus":null,
   "hasFuturePrivilege":false,
   "rogersUser":false,
   "suspendedStatus":null,
   "socialEmail":"",
   "somestringOffersStale":null,
   "somestringcabbagesPrice":null,
   "somestringcabbagesId":null,
   "somestringcabbagesFreeTrial":null,
   "somestringcabbagesOfferPackageId":null,
   "somestringcarrotsPrice":null,
   "somestringcarrotsId":null,
   "somestringcarrotsFreeTrial":null,
   "somestringcarrotsOfferPackageId":null,
   "launchedFromReader":null,
   "userPaymentMethod":null,
   "iseligibleforfreetrial":true,
   "loginTimeStamp":"Tue Oct 11 2016 11:06:29 GMT+0800 (PHT)",
   "latestSubscriptionSource":null
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But actually, I'm currently using JSON.parse already and it works in my browser. But our analytics is showing that tis actually fails to get the userid about 3 - 5% of the time. So, I was hoping a regex might be able to tighten things up. But I'm really not sure. Is there a more basic regex way to get at this? Would that result in better data capture? I'm not sure

Comment: Gotcha. You didn't make that clear in the question. Using a regular expression for this kind of tasks could be as unsecure as parsing the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Hm, so you reckon just sticking with JSON parse would be the most robust way?

Comment: Hard to tell. I would have to look at more of the data. Parsing the object should do the trick, but so could a regex.

Comment: Definitely, imo. I gave another solution for completeness but I would strongly encourage you to use this one.